# Unicode text destroyed inside image PHP

Tags: php, image, unicode

I want to create unicode text inside image via php script. 
here is a sample link which gives output in a destroyed unicode format.
I have tried several font to show myanmar font in correct way but it does not work in any way. How can i show myanmar text in correct format inside image?

Sample output image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcUeQ.png)

sample code is as below:
**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'class.textPainter.php';


if (isset($_GET['size']) && isset($_GET['size'])) {
    $size = $_GET["size"];
} else {
    $size = 30;
}
if (isset($_GET['text']) && isset($_GET['text'])) {
    $text = $_GET["text"];
} else {
    $text = 'Result Text Sample';
}
$optionScores = $_REQUEST['option_scores'];


$imagePath = './imgs/background.png';
$fontFile = './fonts/Pyidaungsu-1.8_Regular.ttf';


$optionScores = json_decode($optionScores, false);




$multiplyer = 3;
$lineX1 = 210;
$initialLineY = -50;
$lineSpace = 100;


$img = new textPainter($imagePath, $text, $fontFile, $size, $optionScores, $multiplyer, $lineX1, $initialLineY, $lineSpace);


if (isset($_GET['x']) && isset($_GET['y'])) {
    $img->setPosition($_GET['x'], $_GET['y']);
} else {
    $img->setPosition();
}

if (isset($_GET["r"]) && isset($_GET["g"]) && isset($_GET["b"])) {
    $img->setTextColor($_GET["r"], $_GET["g"], $_GET["b"]);
} else {
    $img->setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
}

$img->show();
```

**TextPainter.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * TextPainter.php
 *
 * This class allows to print text over a given image.
 * It needs from a TrueType font format (ttf).
 *
 * The resulting image will be show in png format.
 *
 * https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/tree/master/textPainter
 * @license MIT licensed
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2015 alvarotrigo.com - A project by Alvaro Trigo
 */
class textPainter
{
    private $img;
    private $textColor;
    private $position = array();
    private $startPosition = array();

    private $imagePath;
    private $text;
    private $fontFile;
    private $fontSize;
    private $format;


    /**
     * Class Constructor
     *
     * @param string $imagePath background image path
     * @param string $text text to print
     * @param string $fontFile the .ttf font file (TrueType)
     * @param integer $fontSize font size
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct($imagePath, $text, $fontFile, $fontSize, $optionScores, $multiplyer, $lineX1, $initialLineY, $lineSpace)
    {
        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;
        $this->text = $text;
        $this->fontFile = $fontFile;
        $this->fontSize = $fontSize;
        $this->multiplyer = $multiplyer;
        $this->lineX1 = $lineX1;
        $this->initialLineY = $initialLineY;
        $this->lineSpace = $lineSpace;

        $this->setFormat();
        $this->setQuality();
        $this->createImage();
        $this->setTextColor();
        $this->setPosition();

        foreach ($optionScores as $key => $score) {
            $this->colorR = rand(0, 255);
            $this->colorG = rand(0, 255);
            $this->colorB = rand(0, 255);
            $this->initialLineY += $this->lineSpace / 2;

            imagestring($this->img, $this->fontSize, 15, ($this->initialLineY + ($this->lineSpace - 10)), $key, $this->setTextColor());
            if ($score > 0)
                $this->createImageLine($score);

            imagestring($this->img, $this->fontSize, ($this->lineX1 + 5 + $this->multiplyer * $score), ($this->initialLineY + ($this->lineSpace - 10)), $score . " %", $this->setTextColor());
        }


    }

    private function createImageLine($x2)
    {
        imagesetthickness($this->img, 20);
        $this->setLineColor($this->colorR, $this->colorG, $this->colorB);
        $Y = ($this->lineSpace + $this->initialLineY);
        imageline($this->img, $this->lineX1, $Y, ($this->lineX1 + $this->multiplyer * $x2), $Y, $this->lineColor);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the text color using the RGB color scale.
     *
     * @param unknown_type $R red quantity
     * @param unknown_type $G gren quantity
     * @param unknown_type $B blue quantity
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function setTextColor($R = 230, $G = 240, $B = 230)
    {
        $this->textColor = imagecolorallocate($this->img, $R, $G, $B);
    }

    public function setLineColor($R, $G, $B)
    {
        $this->lineColor = imagecolorallocate($this->img, $R, $G, $B);
    }


    /**
     * Shows the resulting image (background image + text)
     * @access public
     */
    public function show()
    {
        //show thumb
        header("Content-type: image/" . $this->format."; charset=UTF-8");

        imagettftext($this->img, $this->fontSize, 0, $this->startPosition["x"], $this->startPosition["y"], $this->textColor, $this->fontFile, $this->text);

        switch ($this->format) {
            case "JPEG":
                imagejpeg($this->img, 'final_image/final_Image.' . $this->format);
                imagejpeg($this->img, NULL, $this->jpegQuality);
                break;
            case "PNG":
                imagepng($this->img, 'final_image/final_Image.' . $this->format);
                imagepng($this->img);
                break;
            case "GIF":
                imagegif($this->img, 'final_image/final_Image.' . $this->format);
                imagegif($this->img);
                break;
            case "WBMP":
                imagewbmp($this->img, 'final_image/final_Image.' . $this->format);
                imagewbmp($this->img);
                break;
            default:
                imagepng($this->img, 'final_image/final_Image.' . $this->format);
                imagepng($this->img);
        }
    }


    public function setQuality($value = 85)
    {
        $this->jpegQuality = $value;
    }

    public function setPosition($x = "center", $y = "top")
    {
        $this->position["x"] = $x;
        $this->position["y"] = $y;

        $dimensions = $this->getTextDimensions();

        if ($x == "left") {
            $this->startPosition["x"] = 0;
        } else if ($x == "center") {
            $this->startPosition["x"] = imagesx($this->img) / 2 - $dimensions["width"] / 2;
        } else if ($x == "right") {
            $this->startPosition["x"] = imagesx($this->img) - $dimensions["width"];
        } //custom
        else {
            $this->startPosition["x"] = $x;
        }

        if ($y == "top") {
            $this->startPosition["y"] = 0 + $dimensions["heigh"];
        } else if ($y == "center") {
            $this->startPosition["y"] = imagesy($this->img) / 2 + $dimensions["heigh"] / 2;
        } else if ($y == "bottom") {
            $this->startPosition["y"] = imagesy($this->img);
        } //custom
        else {
            $this->startPosition["y"] = $y;
        }

    }


    private function setFormat()
    {
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($this->imagePath);
        $extension = $pathInfo['extension'];
        $this->format = strtoupper($extension);

        if ($this->format == "JPG" || $this->format == "JPEG") {
            $this->format = "JPEG";
        } else if ($this->format == "PNG") {
            $this->format = "PNG";
        } else if ($this->format == "GIF") {
            $this->format = "GIF";
        } else if ($this->format == "WBMP") {
            $this->format = "WBMP";
        } else {
            echo "Not Supported File";
            exit();
        }
    }

    private function createImage()
    {
        if ($this->format == "JPEG") {
            $this->img = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->imagePath);
        } else if ($this->format == "PNG") {
            $this->img = imagecreatefrompng($this->imagePath);
        } else if ($this->format == "GIF") {
            $this->img = imagecreatefromgif($this->imagePath);
        } else if ($this->format = "WBMP") {
            $this->img = imagecreatefromwbmp($this->imagePath);
        } else {
            echo "Not Supported File";
            exit();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Sets the font file for the text.
     *
     * @param string $fontFile the .ttf font file (TrueType)
     * @access public
     */
    public function setFontFile($fontFile)
    {
        $this->fontFile = $fontFile;
        $this->setPosition($this->position["x"], $this->position["y"]);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the font size for the text.
     *
     * @param integer $fontSize
     * @access public
     */
    public function setFontSize($fontSize)
    {
        $this->fontSize = $fontSize;
        $this->setPosition($this->position["x"], $this->position["y"]);
    }

    /**
     * It returns the dimensions of the text to print with the given
     * size and font.
     *
     * @return array containing the width and height (width,heigh) of the text to print.
     * @access public
     */
    public function getTextDimensions()
    {
        $dimensions = imagettfbbox($this->fontSize, 0, $this->fontFile, $this->text);

        $minX = min(array($dimensions[0], $dimensions[2], $dimensions[4], $dimensions[6]));
        $maxX = max(array($dimensions[0], $dimensions[2], $dimensions[4], $dimensions[6]));

        $minY = min(array($dimensions[1], $dimensions[3], $dimensions[5], $dimensions[7]));
        $maxY = max(array($dimensions[1], $dimensions[3], $dimensions[5], $dimensions[7]));

        return array(
            'width' => $maxX - $minX,
            'heigh' => $maxY - $minY
        );
    }

    public function getOptionTextDimensions()
    {
        $dimensions = imagettfbbox($this->fontSize, 0, $this->fontFile, $this->optionText);

        $minX = min(array($dimensions[0], $dimensions[2], $dimensions[4], $dimensions[6]));
        $maxX = max(array($dimensions[0], $dimensions[2], $dimensions[4], $dimensions[6]));

        $minY = min(array($dimensions[1], $dimensions[3], $dimensions[5], $dimensions[7]));
        $maxY = max(array($dimensions[1], $dimensions[3], $dimensions[5], $dimensions[7]));

        return array(
            'width' => $maxX - $minX,
            'heigh' => $maxY - $minY
        );
    }
}
```

Please help me to find a solution of my problem.

Comment: What are the exact parameters to the php file that produces the result in the image?

Comment: size=30&option_scores={ကမ်းခြေ:100,%20တော:0,%20ပြည်ပ:0}
sample params like the above ...option_scores is a json param